# CRT linkage with shared library and application

Tags: c, windows, dll, crt, linkage

Windows application links dynamically CRT.After the application executes part of its code it loads shared library.The shared library is linked statically with CRT.

**My question is :**

If the application made some changes to the "CRT state" (for example reopens stdout in some file),
will these changes be valid to in the dll code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, a statically linked CRT is completely independent from a dynamically loaded CRT. The file table is different, the heaps are different, everything is different.

Comment: Thank you.But I still can`t understand why in this case printf result goes to file ,instead of "screen" if reopen was done in the application only.

Comment: It's possible that the CRT uses the [`SetStdHandle` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244(v=vs.85).aspx) to redirect the stdout to a file. In that case, the DLL *would* be affected because there is only one kernel interface per process. I believe MSVC comes with the CRT source code, so you can check by debugging.